# Find every point where the tangent plane is horizontal on z=x-3y+5

Tags: multivariable-calculus

For this, I calculated the partial derivatives with respect to y, and x.

Partial derivative wrt x:1
Partial derivative wrt y:-3

I found then that the plane is tangent at (1,-3,15) since the z=(1+9+15)=15. The answer though is none. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: What? $z=x-3y+5$ describes a plane, so it is equal to its tangent plane at every point. And it's not horizontal! Do you know how you can tell whether a plane is horizontal? On a graph $z=f(x,y)$ the tangent plane is horizontal at points $(x_0,y_0)$ where $\partial f/\partial x$ and $\partial f/\partial y$ both vanish.

Comment: Please do not use tags that are not appropriate.